# No abre SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

creé  otra instancia de conexión SQL SERVER pero cuando voy abrir sql ya no me aparece el icono.
No se si al momento de instaciar la nueva conexión lo haya eliminado.
La pregunta es como puedo solucionar esto, es necesario volver a instalar todo de cero?
Gracias !

Comment: Cuando dices ***ya no me aparece el icono***, ¿a qué te refieres? SQL Server es un servicio en Windows, no tiene una interfaz gráfica. Tal vez te refieres a SQL Server Mangement Studio. ¿Puedes aclarar eso?

Comment: Creo que no adjuntaste las imagenes necesarias para resolver tu duda.